# Is there an easy way to calculate the velocity of an object on a pendulum?

Tags: c++, mathematics

Want to have a rope travel to the mouse on  m2 click and then act as the pivot of a  pendulum, with the player being the bob.
Used some math I don’t really understand to get the angle of the mouse from the player,  and can get the distance very easily. Is that enough information to calculate the velocity of the bob? If not what other information do I need? How do I calculate velocity from that?
Using sfml. Beginner to programming so apologies if this is a stupid question.
Edit: Found out how to find the period and frequency of a pendulum, how do I apply those to velocity?

edit 2: https://youtu.be/9iaEqGOh5WM this video was very helpful

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching for physics tutorials about how to calculate the velocity of a pendulum](https://www.google.com/search?q=velocity+of+pendulum) — how have you tried applying this research in your code so far? Where specifically are you stuck, or how do the results differ from what you expect?

Comment: S@DMGregory Sorry, looked up “how to calculate the velocity of a pendulum” and got some confusing results with mathematical symbols and stuff I don’t really understand, this is much easier to apply. Thanks.

Comment: Show us a result you found and point out the bits where you got confused. That way folks can focus their energy on clarifying the specific bits you need, rather than re-treading ground already covered by countless highschool physics texts (and potentially landing in the same trap of using notation that confuses you).

Comment: http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/211-sp06/class-energy/pendulum.html      How do you “Find potential energy by definition”? What is mg and mv? https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-formula-for-speed-of-pendulum-at-any-point What does a crossed out zero mean? What is sin? What is cos?

Comment: First, search each of those questions. Gravitational potential energy, sine and cosine trigonometric functions, etc. are documented exhaustively on the net, so you'll be able to find your own answers much faster than waiting for a stranger to reply. Once you've informed yourself as much as you can through your own searching, using multiple sources (that one you picked looks like a review question, not the lesson itself — find a tutorial and it will explain more), then you can **edit your question** to explain what you understand so far and what you still need help with.